# Div background image not displaying

Tags: html, css

I'm kinda new to coding and would really appreciate some help with a problem I'm having.
I'm trying to reference an image inside a div but when I check thorugh my browser the image is not displaying.
I'm following this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4kTLpezHDI&list=PL52E0F0A024E913AE.

css:

```
.banner {
   background: url(../img/city-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 695px;
    height: 271px;
}
```

html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Black + White</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container_12">
    <header>
    <h1>Black + White</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">How We Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work Examples</a></li></ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="banner grid_10">
    <p>Some slick phrase would go in here to sum up what the business actually does and stands for.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2"></div>
</header>
<div class="main">
    <div class="grid_5">
        <h1>Services we offer</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="button">Read more</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_5">
        <h1>How we work</h1>
        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <p> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="button">Read more</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_2">
        <blockquote>
            <p>Clean, elegant typography
            matched with sharp lines
            and precise spacing leads
            to a professional look
            and feel</p>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
<footer><p><strong>black+white themes via </strong><a href="http://themeforest.net">Themeforest</a></p></footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "style.css">
--------------------------------------^------------
```

You're missing `href`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

[starting with HTML + CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html)

Comment: Thanks missed that. It's still not displaying though

Comment: Is your image path good? When you inspect, do you get any error ?

Comment: @AlexanderAndersen your code is working with Vucko's code modifucation. you might have added incorrect path of your image. refer this http://jsfiddle.net/JxqZC/

Comment: I'm using the editor brackets in which you can hold on an image path and if the image appears it should be correct which it does when I try. The weird thing though is that when I inspect in the browser it can't even find the image.

Comment: @Ayush I tried using your path but it still won't appear in the browser

Comment: @AlexanderAndersen the problem is in the image path. Can you share your site's link?

Comment: @Vucko It's a local image on my computer that i'm referencing. I'm following the tutorial pointed out above to learn how to slice a psd and turn it into code.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the *href* in the link tag here.

I highly suggest that you use element browser inspection tools to checks errors of this type, they are easy to use and they will get you out of a lot of trouble.
Download, install and use the code element inspection tool on your browser: Firebug for firefox, DragonFly for Opera, or use the built-in tool for Chrome. You can go to that element in HTML code, and check if the code is used properly. You can also make temporary HTML/JS/CSS changes on-the-fly to test it. This can be useful in general in web developing, to check the code if the code is executed as desired in browsers easily or to make changes to test cases and things.

Comment: I added the href earlier after I got the tip that I missed it. I've tried inspecting in chrome but it can't even find the image.

Comment: Try clearing out your browser cache, and reload the page. Inform us if you can see it now.

Comment: Tried it but since it's just local on my computer and simply a html that I'm opening I don't think it works

Comment: Did you inspect the element, to see if CSS content is accessible and applies to that element?